# Site Nav Accessibility - Enter key doesn't open sub navigation

Tags: javascript, navigation, accessibility

I'm building site navigation. If I tab into a category and hit enter nothing happens. If I press the spacebar I get a flash of the subnav but then it disappears.

I am using a button element to trigger the subnav instead of an anchor tag. If I switch to an anchor tag then it works.

What is causing this to happen in my Javascript and is there a way to make this better?

I've put the entire nav on codepen here: https://codepen.io/sibarad/pen/gORqevp?editors=1010

Here is a basic example of the html:

```
<ul class="site-menu header-container--nav-mobile">
   <li class="site-menu__item site-menu__item--has-submenu">
      <button tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Nav Link 1
         <span class="site-menu__submenu-icon">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" width="16" height="16">
               <use xlink:href="#mobile-nav-arrow" />
            </svg>
          </span>
       </button>
       <!-- Main Nav Item 1 Sub-item -->
       <ul class="site-menu__submenu" id="dt_nav-accountbilling">
          <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
          <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
       </ul><!-- /Main Nav Item 1 Sub-item -->
     </li><!-- /Main Nav Item 1 -->
```

Here is my JS:

```
// Submenu Hide/Show Mobile and Desktop
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".site-menu__item--has-submenu");
const subButton = document.querySelectorAll(".site-menu__item--has-submenu button");

// Activate Submenu
function toggleItem() {
  if (this.classList.contains("submenu-active")) {
  this.classList.remove("submenu-active");
  } else if (site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
  } else {
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
  }
}

// Event Listeners
for (let item of items) {
    if (item.querySelector(".site-menu__submenu")) {
      item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
      item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleItem, false);
    }
}

// Close Submenu From Anywhere
function closeSubmenu(e) {
  let isClickInside = site_menu.contains(e.target);

  if (!isClickInside && site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
  }
}

// Event listener for Close Submenu
document.addEventListener("click", closeSubmenu, false);
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    //if esc key was not pressed in combination with ctrl or alt or shift
    const isNotCombinedKey = !(event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.shiftKey);
    if (isNotCombinedKey) {
      closeSubmenu(false);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offending code is here:

```js
for (let item of items) {
    if (item.querySelector(".site-menu__submenu")) {
      item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
      <!-- this will be triggered as well, reversing your toggle -->
      item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleItem, false);
    }
}
```

You are adding 2 listeners that will both trigger on pressing <kbd>space</kbd> etc.

You do not need the second listener as you used a `<button>` which will treat <kbd>Space</kbd> etc. as a click event!

Removing the second listener will make the drop down work as expected.

```js
for (let item of items) {
    if (item.querySelector(".site-menu__submenu")) {
      item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
    }
}
```

### Fixed code and fiddle

```js
/////////////
// Site header/navigation
////////////

(function() {

  'use strict';

// Hamburger Animation toggle
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.js-primary-nav__toggle');
const hamburger_text = document.querySelector('.js-primary-nav__toggle-text');
// Mobile Container for Nav Content
const site_menu = document.querySelector('.main-site-menu');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('toggle-active');
  if (hamburger_text.textContent === "Menu") {
    hamburger_text.textContent = "Close";
    site_menu.classList.add('is-active');
    hamburger.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
    document.body.classList.toggle('lock-scroll');
  } else {
    hamburger_text.textContent = "Menu";
    site_menu.classList.remove('is-active');
    hamburger.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    document.body.classList.toggle('lock-scroll');
  }

});

// Submenu Hide/Show Mobile and Desktop
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".site-menu__item--has-submenu");
const subButton = document.querySelectorAll(".site-menu__item--has-submenu button");

// Activate Submenu
function toggleItem() {
  if (this.classList.contains("submenu-active")) {
    this.classList.remove("submenu-active");
  } else if (site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
  } else {
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
  }
}

// Event Listeners
for (let item of items) {
    if (item.querySelector(".site-menu__submenu")) {
      item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
      //item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleItem, false);
    }
}

// Close Submenu From Anywhere
function closeSubmenu(e) {
  let isClickInside = site_menu.contains(e.target);

  if (!isClickInside && site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    site_menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
  }
}

// Event listener for Close Submenu
document.addEventListener("click", closeSubmenu, false);
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    //if esc key was not pressed in combination with ctrl or alt or shift
    const isNotCombinedKey = !(event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.shiftKey);
    if (isNotCombinedKey) {
      closeSubmenu(false);
    }
  }
});

}());
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.os-container--max-width, .header-container--nav-mobile, .header-container {
  max-width: 1272px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.os-container--fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.os-flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
@media (min-width: 672px) {
  .os-flex-grid {
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-right: -12px;
  }
}

.os-flex--stack-mobile {
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width: 672px) {
  .os-flex--stack-mobile {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.os-flex-grid__col {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0px;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 672px) {
  .os-flex-grid__col {
    flex-basis: 0;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
  }
}

.os-flex-grid__col--12, .cms-flex-grid__col--12 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.os-flex-grid__col--9, .cms-flex-grid__col--9 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.os-flex-grid__col--6 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.os-flex-grid__col--4 {
  flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
}

.os-flex-grid__col--3 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.os-flex-grid__col--2 {
  flex-basis: 16.6666666667%;
}

.site-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}
.site-header a {
  color: #0e75c4;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-header {
    margin-bottom: 42px;
  }
}

.site-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: normal;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .header-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

.header-container--nav-mobile {
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .header-container--nav-mobile {
    padding-left: inital;
    padding-right: inital;
  }
}

.header-main {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px -2px rgba(18, 32, 42, 0.12);
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .header-main {
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-top: 32px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
  }
}

.header-main__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-logo img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 131px;
}
@media (min-width: 672px) {
  .header-logo img {
    max-width: 260px;
  }
}

.header-component-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.header-component-wrap a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header-component-wrap a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.header-component-wrap svg {
  fill: #213848;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .header-component-wrap svg {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .header-component-wrap {
    align-items: center;
  }
}

.header-main__text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0e75c4;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}
.header-main__text:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #0e75c4;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .header-main__text {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: normal;
  }
}

.site-menu,
.site-menu__submenu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.site-menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #213848;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
}

.main-site-menu {
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #213848;
  padding-bottom: 9.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .main-site-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow-x: initial;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.main-site-menu.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.site-menu__item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.site-menu__item a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.site-menu__item > a {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item > a {
    padding: 24px 16px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1272px) {
  .site-menu__item > a {
    padding: 24px;
  }
}
.site-menu__item > a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item > a:hover {
    background-color: #0e75c4;
  }
}

.site-menu__item--has-submenu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2f4656;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item--has-submenu {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item.site-menu__button {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}

.site-menu__item--has-submenu button {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.333333333s ease-in-out;
}
.site-menu__item--has-submenu button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item--has-submenu button:hover {
    background-color: #2f4656;
    color: #61bef0;
  }
}
.site-menu__item--has-submenu button:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #128ddd;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item--has-submenu button {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1240px) {
  .site-menu__item--has-submenu button {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.site-menu__submenu-icon svg {
  width: 16px;
  height: 9.33px;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__submenu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

.mobile-nav-arrow {
  width: 16px;
  height: 9.33px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  fill: #128ddd;
}

.site-menu__submenu {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #2f4656;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: max-height 0.4s 0s ease-in-out;
  display: none;
  max-height: 0;
  left: -999rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__submenu {
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    min-width: 302px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1240px) {
  .site-menu__submenu {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item--has-submenu:nth-child(7) > .site-menu__submenu {
    min-width: 185px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1240px) {
  .site-menu__item--has-submenu:nth-child(7) > .site-menu__submenu {
    min-width: 295px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1272px) {
  .site-menu__item--has-submenu:nth-child(7) > .site-menu__submenu {
    min-width: 302px;
  }
}

.submenu-active .site-menu__submenu {
  display: flex;
  max-height: inherit;
  left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .submenu-active .site-menu__submenu {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .submenu-active {
    background-color: #2f4656;
  }
}
.submenu-active > button {
  color: #61bef0;
}

.site-menu__submenu-col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__subitem {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.site-menu__subitem a {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.site-menu__subitem a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__subitem a {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }
}

.site-menu__item--mobile-search {
  display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .site-menu__item--mobile-search {
    display: none;
  }
}
.site-menu__item--mobile-search input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  background-image: url(../images/search-icon.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 98% center;
  border: 1px solid #687782;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.primary-nav__toggle {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 48px;
}
@media (min-width: 1056px) {
  .primary-nav__toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}

.primary-nav__toggle-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #213848;
  margin: 6px auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.primary-nav__toggle-bar--bottom {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.toggle-active .primary-nav__toggle-bar--top {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-7px, 6px);
}

.toggle-active .primary-nav__toggle-bar--middle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle-active .primary-nav__toggle-bar--bottom {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -5px);
}

.lock-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header site-header--home">
      

      <nav class="site-nav" role="navigation" aria-label="main menu">
        <!-- main header -->
        <div class="header-main">
          <div class="header-container header-main__items">
            <a class="header-logo" href="">Logo</a>
            <div class="header-component-wrap">
              <!-- Mobile Hamburger Toggle -->
              <button class="primary-nav__toggle js-primary-nav__toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="primary-nav__toggle-bar primary-nav__toggle-bar--top"></span>
                <span class="primary-nav__toggle-bar primary-nav__toggle-bar--middle"></span>
                <span class="primary-nav__toggle-bar primary-nav__toggle-bar--bottom"></span>
                <span class="header-main__text js-primary-nav__toggle-text">Menu</span>
              </button><!-- /Mobile Hamburger Toggle -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Site Navigation Wrappers -->
        <div class="header-container">
          <div class="main-site-menu">

            <!-- Site Nav -->
            <ul class="site-menu header-container--nav-mobile">
              <!-- Main Nav Item 1 -->
              <li class="site-menu__item site-menu__item--has-submenu">
                <button tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Nav Link 1
                  <span class="site-menu__submenu-icon">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" width="16" height="16">
                                   <use xlink:href="#mobile-nav-arrow" />
                          </svg>
                  </span>
                </button>
                <!-- Main Nav Item 1 Sub-item -->
                <ul class="site-menu__submenu" id="dt_nav-accountbilling">
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /Main Nav Item 1 Sub-item -->
              </li><!-- /Main Nav Item 1 -->
              <!-- Main Nav Item 2 -->
              <li class="site-menu__item site-menu__item--has-submenu">
                <button tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Nav Link 2
                  <span class="site-menu__submenu-icon">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" width="16" height="16">
                                   <use xlink:href="#mobile-nav-arrow" />
                          </svg>
                  </span>
                </button>
                <!-- Main Nav Item 2 Sub-item -->
                <ul class="site-menu__submenu" id="dt_nav-savemoney">
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /Main Nav Item 2 Sub-item -->
              </li><!-- /Main Nav Item 2 -->
              <!-- Main Nav Item 3 -->
              <li class="site-menu__item site-menu__item--has-submenu">
                <button tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Nav Link 3
                  <span class="site-menu__submenu-icon">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" width="16" height="16">
                                   <use xlink:href="#mobile-nav-arrow" />
                          </svg>
                  </span>
                </button>
                <!-- Main Nav Item 3 Sub-item -->
                <ul class="site-menu__submenu" id="dt_nav-outagesstorms">
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /Main Nav Item 3 Sub-item -->
              </li><!-- /Main Nav Item 3 -->
              <!-- Main Nav Item 4 -->
              <li class="site-menu__item site-menu__item--has-submenu">
                <button tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Nav Link 4
                  <span class="site-menu__submenu-icon">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" width="16" height="16">
                                   <use xlink:href="#mobile-nav-arrow" />
                          </svg>
                  </span>
                </button>
                <!-- Main Nav Item 4 Sub-item -->
                <ul class="site-menu__submenu" id="dt_nav-safety">
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                  <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /Main Nav Item 4 Sub-item -->
              </li><!-- /Main Nav Item 4 -->
            </ul><!-- /Site Nav -->
          </div>
        </div><!-- /Site Navigation Wrappers -->
      </nav>
    </header><!-- /Begin ES Site Header -->
```